# How to create a Job and a secret from Kubernetes Javascript Client

Tags: javascript, typescript, kubernetes

I am trying to work my way into the [kubernetes javascript client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript).

My goal is to create a Job and a secret from inside the cluster.

The [kubernetes javascript client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript) provide examples on how to create a [in-cluster config](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript/blob/master/examples/in-cluster.js) and make simples API calls , but the generated documentation is no big help if you want to interact with other kubernetes objects (Jobs and Secret in my case)...

The documentation reference all the classes , but that's all.

So , do you have already worked with the Kubernetes javascript client ? Is there a more precise documentation or more examples ? (I wasn't succesful in my reshearsh)

Or , do you know how to create Jobs/Secret from the Client?

I Won't post my code here , because I only made the in-cluster config , it's only a copy from the repo example.

Thanks a Lot in advance! :)

Comment: Hello,
I thing based on this example https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript/blob/master/examples/ingress.js and the documentation of kubernetes https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#running-an-example-job,
You should be able to create easily what you are looking for :)
Best

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'm new to javascript and Kubernetes I didn't tic when i saw that example ! I'll do some testing , and come close this issue if this worked :)

Comment: Sadly , I still need to know the name of the functions to create the Jobs and Namespace Object. With a little meddling  with Code , I found the name of the function to create a secret : "createNamespacedSecret" , but I didn't found the name of the function to create Jobs

Comment: Have a look to this issue https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript/issues/117, createNamespacedJob should do the trick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So , after a little meddling with the [Kubernetes Javascript Client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript) and with the help of the commentary of @François I found what I was looking to achieve.

The documentation of the K8s javascript client is very "minimal" , an the best way to see what is possible is using a good Code Editor (Code for me).

Based on [this](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript/blob/master/examples/ingress.js) example  you see the createNamespacedIngress , and all the other K8s object linked with the CoreV1Api are created with the same nomenclature.

If you want to create an object that is not managed by the CoreV1Api , you need to use the makeApiClient method on the Api you need to interacy with.

So , for creating a Job , I needed to use the BatchV1Api.

I'll try to upload an example on the Javasript client repo , to maybe , help more poor lost souls like me.
Snippet of the code:

```
const k8sCoreV1Api = kc.makeApiClient(k8s.CoreV1Api); // we call the CoreV1Api that will be used for the creation of the secrets
```

const k8sBatchV1Api = kc.makeApiClient(k8s.BatchV1Api); //we call the BatchV1Api that will be used for the creation of the jobs

Here is the whole sample here : https://pastebin.com/FXWA17RQ